# Can one "derive something" without specifying from what/where you derived that thing?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it possible to say that "I derived my research question", without having to say where you derived it from? E.g.

*I derived my research question.*

**OR**

*I derived my research question from this data.*

Which would be more appropriate?

Comment: As per [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/derive): Obtain something **from (a specified source)**.

Comment: But the source may be and frequently is obvious in context, without being mentioned in a sentence.

Comment: It is also possible to say: "How do we derive it?", where the source is not specified but is asked about. Also a transitive in logic: "That is what I derive" = "That is what I think" or "That is what I came up with": which also doesn't explain where something was derived from.

Comment: I've just taken a look at [CoCAE](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and found that approximately 78/101 results for **derive** are used in conjunction with **from**, suggesting that -- while not at all common -- **derived** can definitely be used without **from**. Please use with caution, however, since the nuances behind them are a bit murky. There are some other uses, as @Rob suggested, but these are somewhat esoteric and won't be encountered regularly. With that said, if you do have a source from which you derive something, it should really be included in the sentence.

Comment: The use of the word *derive* shifts the focus to the (unstated) source. Avoid it.

Comment: Grammatically one could, but what would the point of saying it that way? Every reader would either care nothing, or ask where or how…

Answer (score 1):

I did the research and derived my question.

This might be a good way of phrasing it since it still doesn't state where exactly it's from, yet it does specify that it's from someplace - in this case - research in general.

I don't know, though, where and how exactly you want to use it, but I hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to say that "I derived my research question", without having to say where you derived it from?

You can say either:

> I derived my research question.
>
> ***or***
>
> I derived my research question from this data.

Notice that the second sentence doesn't literally explain exactly ***where*** you derived it from, the reader still needs more information to know what "this data" is. In the first example you say "I have what I need" and in the second example you say "I got what I need from something".

Either is correct but be prepared to be asked for more information. It is also your right to not provide more information. Even if specifics are vague that doesn't make the grammar, spelling or other aspects of the sentence in any way incorrect.

There is a comment on the question that "usage without specifying the source of the information occurs approximately 22% of the time", that doesn't make such usage uncommon, nor does it mean such usage is incorrect.